# Open CV android app stop working

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm working on an android - openCV project, however I get some magical errors on my way and I need your help.

Here is my **MainActivity.java** file

```
package com.letscreate.cizgilestir;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Cartoonify";

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private static final int GOTO_CAMERA = 2;

    private Bitmap mBitmapModified;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private ProgressBar mProgBar;
    private TextView mInfoText;
    private boolean fProcess=false;

    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;


    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            if(status == LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS) {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully.");
            } else {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mProgBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prog_bar);
        mProgBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mInfoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_message);

        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekbarvalue);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                          boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        SeekBar SeekBar04 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.SeekBar04);
        final TextView TextView04 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

        SeekBar04.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                          boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView04.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        SeekBar SeekBar02 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.SeekBar02);
        final TextView TextView02 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView02);

        SeekBar02.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                          boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView02.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        SeekBar SeekBar03 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.SeekBar03);
        final TextView TextView03 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView03);

        SeekBar03.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                          boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView03.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_2_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
        ImageView imview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        if(mBitmap != null && fProcess) {
            imview.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
            mInfoText.setText(R.string.info_processing);
            mProgBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            BitmapProcessTask bpt = new BitmapProcessTask(imview, mProgBar, mInfoText);
            mBitmapModified = mBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565,false);
            bpt.execute(mBitmapModified);
            fProcess = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toonify, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void toonify(View view) {
        fProcess = true;
        onResume();
    }

    public void restore(View view) {
        ImageView imview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imview.setImageBitmap(mBitmapModified);
    }

    public void dispatchGalleryIntent(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }

    public void dispatchCameraIntent(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File f = null;
        try {
            f = setUpPhotoFile();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            f = null;
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent, GOTO_CAMERA);
    }
//
//  public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
//      final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
//      final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
//      List<ResolveInfo> list =
//              packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
//      return list.size() > 0;
//  }
//
//  private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) {
//      Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
//      mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
//      mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
//  }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                mBitmap = null;
                try {
                    mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(mBitmap != null) {
                    ImageView imview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
                    imview.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
//                  Log.i(TAG,"when is this happening");
//                  mBitmapModified = mBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565,false);
                }
            } else if(requestCode == GOTO_CAMERA) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Ativity Completed");
                if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Taking Picture");
                    setPic();
                    Log.i(TAG, "setPic Done");
                    galleryAddPic();
                    Log.i(TAG, "gallery added");
                    mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void saveImage(View view) {
        SeekBar seek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        int seekValue = seek.getProgress();
        Log.i(TAG, "Seeking "+seekValue);
        ImageView imview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        if(imview != null) {

        }

        if(mBitmap != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "saving image to gallery");
            saveImageToGallery(mBitmapModified);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Used to save bitmaps and put them in the photo gallery.
     */
    private void saveImageToGallery(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/Cartoonified");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US);
        String timestamp = sdf.format(new Date());
        String fname = "Cartoonify-"+ timestamp +".jpg";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            mInfoText.setText("Saved: " + fname);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }
                });
//      sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
    }

    private void setPic() {

        /* There isn't enough memory to open up more than a couple camera photos */
        /* So pre-scale the target bitmap into which the file is decoded */

        /* Get the size of the ImageView */
        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

        /* Get the size of the image */
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
        int scaleFactor = 1;
        if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
            scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);
        }

        /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
//      Log.i(TAG,"when is this happening");
//      mBitmapModified = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap);
        /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView */
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/Cartoonified");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US);
        String timestamp = sdf.format(new Date());
        String fname = "Cartoonify-"+ timestamp +".jpg";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        return file;
    }
    private File setUpPhotoFile() throws IOException {

        File f = createImageFile();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();

        return f;
    }

    private class BitmapProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imviewRef;
        private final WeakReference<ProgressBar> progBarRef;
        private final WeakReference<TextView> textViewRef;

        public BitmapProcessTask(ImageView imview, ProgressBar progBar, TextView textView) {
            imviewRef = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imview);
            progBarRef = new WeakReference<ProgressBar>(progBar);
            textViewRef = new WeakReference<TextView>(textView);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {

            Bitmap bmp = params[0];


            Mat rgba = new Mat();
            Mat rgb = new Mat();
            Mat gray = new Mat();

            Mat smallrgb = new Mat();
            Mat edges = new Mat();
            Mat tempA1 = new Mat();
            Mat tempA2 = new Mat();
            Mat tempB1 = new Mat();

            Mat result = new Mat();

            Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, rgba);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, rgb, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

            Log.i(TAG, "size: " + gray.size().toString());
            TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekbarvalue);
            Integer MedFilterParam = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
            if(MedFilterParam%2==0) MedFilterParam--;
            Log.i(TAG, "Median Filter Parameter = "+MedFilterParam);
            Imgproc.medianBlur(gray, tempA1, MedFilterParam);

            Imgproc.Canny(tempA1, edges, 50, 90);

            Size dilateSize = new Size(2,2);
            Imgproc.dilate(edges, edges, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, dilateSize));

            List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
            Imgproc.findContours(edges, contours, tempA2, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            Log.i(TAG, "num contours: " + contours.size());
            List<MatOfPoint> keepContours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

            text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
            Integer EdgeFilterthreshold = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());

            Log.i(TAG, "Edge Filter Threshold = "+EdgeFilterthreshold);

            for(MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
                if(Imgproc.contourArea(contour) > EdgeFilterthreshold)
                    keepContours.add(contour);
            }

            double scale = 4;
            Size smallSize = new Size(rgb.size().width/scale, rgb.size().height/scale);
            Imgproc.resize(rgb, smallrgb, smallSize);


            text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
            Integer BFReps = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());

            Log.i(TAG, "Bilateral Filter Repetitions = "+BFReps);

            text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView03);
            Integer BFSize = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());

            Log.i(TAG, "Bilateral Filter Kernel Size = "+BFSize);

            double sigmaC = 15;
            double sigmaS = 7;
            for(int i = 0; i < BFReps; i++) {
                Imgproc.bilateralFilter(smallrgb, tempB1, BFSize, sigmaC, sigmaS);
                Imgproc.bilateralFilter(tempB1, smallrgb, BFSize, sigmaC, sigmaS);
            }

            Imgproc.resize(smallrgb, rgb, rgba.size(), 0, 0, Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR);

            Imgproc.medianBlur(rgb, rgb, 7);

            Size size = rgb.size();
            double colorScale = 24;
            byte[] pixels = new byte[3];
            Log.i(TAG, CvType.typeToString(rgb.type()));
            for(int row = 0; row < size.height; row++) {
                for(int col = 0; col < size.width; col++) {
                    rgb.get(row, col, pixels);
                    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        int pix = (int)pixels[i];
                        pix = (int)(Math.floor((pix) / colorScale) * colorScale);
                        if(pix < -128) pix = -128;
                        if(pix > 127) pix = 127;
                        pixels[i] = (byte)pix;
                    }
                    rgb.put(row, col, pixels);
                }
            }
            Imgproc.medianBlur(rgb, rgb, 11);

            Imgproc.drawContours(rgb, keepContours, -1, new Scalar(30,30,30), -1);

            Imgproc.cvtColor(rgb, result, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2RGBA);

            Utils.matToBitmap(result, bmp);

            rgba.release();
            rgb.release();
            gray.release();
            smallrgb.release();
            edges.release();
            tempA1.release();
            tempA2.release();
            tempB1.release();
            result.release();
            return bmp;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if(isCancelled()) {
                bitmap = null;
            }
            if(imviewRef != null) {
                ImageView imview = imviewRef.get();
                if(imview != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "setting the bitmap now...");
                    imview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
            if(progBarRef != null) {
                ProgressBar progBar = progBarRef.get();
                if(progBar != null) {
                    progBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
            if(textViewRef != null) {
                TextView textView = textViewRef.get();
                if(textView != null) {
                    textView.setText(R.string.info_process_complete);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I cannot add layout file because of stack overflow's new thread rules. But if you require I will try to add it too.

The problem is that I get application stopped working warning and there is no explanation in Android Monitor tab?

Are there any mistakes in the java code?

Comment: Do you see any errors in log cat?

Comment: Hey Ivan i checked twice and i got this on my last check.                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)